# need a batch file

Tags: batch-file

source path "S:\nk\Reporting\03.2013"
Target path  "S:\nk\final_reporting

want's to moov file "Balance Sheet.xls" from source to Target path

note: (date folder change every month i.e.04.2013, 05.2013.... etc)

can I have a batch file to do this activity?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to extract the month and year from the current date. The problem with `%date%` is that it does not have a predictable format, as it might be changed by the user. A more reliable way is to use **wmic** instead.

Try this code to get you started

```
@echo off
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
  set /a mm=100+%%D
  set mmyyyy=%mm:~1%.%%F
)
echo move S:\nk\Reporting\%mmyyyy%\balance.xls S:\nk\final_reporting
```

WMIC returns the month without the leading zero, so you'll have to transform it with a simple arithmetic.

Comment: wmic is not includet in xp

Comment: OP does not specify XP in the question. Anyway, it is available in XP professional and above, and is a free download from Microsoft for other versions.

Comment: OP does not excluded xp in his question until now. there are thousands of time distributing  tools in the net, mostly for free.

Comment: so, according to microsoft docs http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc181088.aspx you have wmic. did you try it?

Comment: you mean windows 2008 or windows 7? it should work on both, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%i IN (20/11/2012 20/01/2012 20/01/2013 20/01/2009 20/04/2013 
            20/02/2013 20/03/2013 20/08/2012 20/09/2000 20/01/2000
       ) DO CALL :calc %%i
GOTO :eof

:calc
SET dayte=%1
SET today=%dayte:~0,2%-%dayte:~3,2%-%dayte:~-4%
SET /a lastmonth=%dayte:~-4%%dayte:~3,2%-1
IF %lastmonth:~-2%==00 SET /a lastmonth-=88
SET lastmonth=%lastmonth:~-2%.%lastmonth:~0,4%
ECHO with date=%dayte% today=%today% lastmonth=%lastmonth%

GOTO :eof
```

First little problem is that `%date%` is a **MAGIC VARIABLE**. It is supplied by the OS. `HOWEVER` if you assign a value to `DATE` as you have with your

```
set date="%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%"
```

then the environment variable `%date%` overrides the **MAGIC VARIABLE** (so don't do it - same with `%RANDOM%` and others...)

So, the code I've shown uses my date format - all you need to do is change to suit yours.

Essentially, `today` is being set as you had set `date`

`lastmonth` is set to the concatenation of the year and month, then one is subtracted, so in April, 2013 `lastmonth` would be set to the `/a` arithmetic result of the expression (201304 - 1)
Then, if the last two characters of `lastmonth` are now "00" then the date was January, so by subtracting 88, we subtract 1 year and add 12 months. 100-12=88.

Then reformat the result to the desired structure, and all's done!

Comment: thx peter for your help..I have discribed more, what i am looking for, can you plz halp again?